# RHEL 7 - Execute command over SSH session result different from execute directly

Tags: shell-script, shell

I'm in a situation where I have a installation progress involves a command, let's say I have command `patch` (not real one) for installing, and I would like to fill `No` on the first prompt, with a user that is cust, I made a script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
patch -i <package> << EOF
No
EOF
```

Then I put this file as `chmod 777`
I executed it by `./installScript.sh` it got permission denied, but `. installScript.sh` works like a charm.
If I execute the command `patch` manually, it would also works normally. Below are questions that I would like to ask:
1/ I knew the differences of `./file` and `. file` before through this forum, but I don't understand why shell affects the privilege?
2/ is there a way I could by pass this in my script ? The target is that I can use `./installScript.sh` rather than `. installScript.sh`

Comment: "chmod 777" is always wrong

Comment: could you give me another command to set up the permission ?

Comment: Usually its 755. But anyway, check the permission on the file by using `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

> I knew the differences of ./file and . file before through this forum, but I don't understand why shell affects the privilege?

I don't either. But things to check....

- does /bin/bash exist and is it executable?
- is your script on a filesystem mounted with noexec?
- are you running any MAC system (apparmor, SELinux, smack)?

> is there a way I could by pass this in my script ? The target is that I can use ./installScript.sh rather than . installScript.sh

running `ssh user@remote "bash installScript.sh"` whould be equivalent to `. installScript.sh` in an interactive session.

Comment: 1. /bin/bash does exist
2. I have put mount mode to exec
3. I did not check this, will see this and get back to you